# How to put conversion operation in a for loop?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, file-conversion

Below is the code to convert **.tim** file to **ascii** file for one particular file. But what I need is to convert 500 files(**.tim**). I also need to save the **.ascii** file in SAME name as the **.tim** file name like below for all 500 files.

```
bin=fopen('file_01.tim','r'); 
 ascii = fread(bin, [43,21000], 'float32'); 
 data_values=ascii';
  dlmwrite('file_01.xls', data_values, 'delimiter', '\t', ...
     'precision', '%.6f','newline','pc');
```

Using a "for loop" to do the conversion and save the **ascii** file with the same name of the **tim**, was my first thought but I don't know how to that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [dir](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html) to get a list of all the filenames in your folder and then proceed just as you have but using replacing `'file_01.tim'` with `[D(ii).name]`

e.g.

```
D = dir('*.tim');

for ii = 1:size(D,1)
    bin=fopen(D(ii).name,'r');
    %your processing etc
    savename = [strtok(D(ii).name,'.'), '.xls']; %Change the file ext from .tim to .xls
    dlmwrite(savename, ...
```